# Array Formula omits IF / AND functions

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-arrays

I'm using a series of IF and IF/AND functions to assign a set value according to, sometimes one set or two set of colums. While creating a range and Array Formula to apply that to all posible new columns, the IF/AND functions are disabled. All in Google Sheets.

Here is an example (both if/and are ommited from the result of the formula, they can only work if I remove the H2:H and J2:J ranges, that allow me to apply to all new rows :

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Maestría en Finanzas",H2:H)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("EGADE en Línea",J2:J))),"MAFO",
IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Maestría en Finanzas",H2:H)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("EGADE En Línea",J2:J))),"MAFO",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Maestría en Finanzas Online",H2:H,1)),"MAFO",
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Maestría en Finanzas",H2:H,1)),"MAF",
"No Match"
))))))))))))
)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

`AND` does not work with array formulas; you have to use `*` instead. (Likewise, `OR` does not work with array formulas, and you must use `+` instead.) You also have redundancies in the formula.

It is always difficult to try to write a formula without access to the spreadsheet, layout, data types, etc. And, of course, there's no way to test a formula in the dark like this. But you can try this instead of what you have:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(H2:H="",,IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Maestría en Finanzas",H2:H))),"No Match","MAF")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Maestría en Finanzas",H2:H))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("EGADE en Línea",J2:J))+(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Maestría en Finanzas Online",H2:H)))),"O","")))`

If this does not work, consider sharing a link to your sheet or to a copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with your formula except that you have far too many closing brackets at the end.

This should work:

`=arrayformula(IF(H2:H="",,IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Maestría en Finanzas",H2:H)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("EGADE en Línea",J2:J))),"MAFO",IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Maestría en Finanzas",H2:H)), ISNUMBER(SEARCH("EGADE En Línea",J2:J))),"MAFO",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Maestría en Finanzas Online",H2:H,1)),"MAFO",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Maestría en Finanzas",H2:H,1)),"MAF","No Match"))))))`

---

**SAMPLE**

[image: sample]

Comment: `and()` is an aggregating function and will not give row-by-row results in an array formula. Use boolean arithmetic instead.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. I DID test before I submitted my answer. To be honest, I was half inclined to add this answer as a comment since the OP didn't provide any data. But given that the OP's formula was so fouled up, I thought it best to confirm the structure of the formula and let the OP deal with the implications in their data.